# Joomla displaying blank page after login after moving the installation from one server to another

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

I just moved my current office Joomla 1.5.8 instalation from the server(linux) to my local machines (winxp) so I can work locally and only upload the changes.

The thing is after downloading all the files and installing a backup of the remote DB on my local machine I found myself unable to login to the administrator panel, I can see the frontpage but not login :/

So far, I have googled alot this problem, but most people seem to be experiencing this problem while upgrading from joomla 1.0

To make sure the problem was not on permissions for the files,I did a separate brand new joomla instalation on another folder and it worked just fine, I could access the website and I also could login to admin page, then I changed the config file to connect to the joomla I'm trying to move and now I find myself again unable to login :/

I think the problem is on the DB however I already tried searching for specific paths but no luck

Does anyone has another Idea?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to change following variable in your local configuration file with you local values.

```
var $offline = '0';
var $log_path = 'Your local joomla path\logs';
var $tmp_path = 'Your local joomla path\tmp';
var $live_site = 'local url will be here';
var $dbtype = 'mysql';
var $host = 'local db host';
var $user = 'DB user for local';
var $db = 'Db name for local';
var $dbprefix = 'DB prefix whatever you have set, by default jos_';
var $password = 'your DB password for local';
```

Comment: I already changed everything on the configuration to fit perfectly, I even clone the config from the new installation but as soon as I point it to the old DB it stops working :/

A weird thing I noticed yesterday, and I really think this has to do with the DB is that if I connet remotely to the DB, with a local installation, still wont work, but the installation on the webserver conneting to the very same DB works :/

Answer (score 2):

You probably have LDAP or openid authentication enabled and thats what is causing this blank page while you try to login.

Just go to your database and go to your:
jos_plugins

And edit the plugins which are either openid or LDAP
set their published status from 1 to '0'

Case solved.

Comment: In my case, I have SJSB Authentication enabled, which I didn't configure the plugin SJSB yet. Therefore, there is a chance to encounter blank page after login.

Answer (score 0):

Does your site use any kind of extra authentication?  Mine used the LDAP Authentication plugin.  MY local machine couldn't connect to the LDAP server.  After turning LDAP authentication off (only use Joomla authentication) it worked.

edit the jos_plugins table in mysql to set published from 1 to 0 for any extra authentication plugins you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I  have discussed this issue in details here: http://www.itoctopus.com/blank-page-on-joomla-login

In most cases we have seen, Joomla is trying to load a file that no longer exists.